# Check response of one backend before proxying to another

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy, openresty, traefik

I have two backends in two locations behind an Nginx frontend. Backend A implements authentication with OAuth. Backend B doesn't.

I think a lazy way of adding authentication for location B would be to send each request to backend A first. The flow I have in mind:

```
request for /b/kitten.png --> [ nginx ]
                              [ nginx ] --> request for /index.html --> [backend A]
                            if A responds 200:
                              [ nginx ] --> request for /kitten.png --> [backend B]
                            otherwise return what A returned (redirect to OAuth)
```

Is this possible in Nginx? If not, maybe in OpenResty/HAProxy/Traefik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but slightly too long for comment:

The set-up you describe is in concept similar to a fairly common strategy :

- offload the authentication to one system
- use your reverse proxy to enforce that only authenticated clients can access your other applications/back-ends (by inspecting the request)
- unauthenticated clients  get refused by the reverse proxy  (and/or ideally  redirected to a login page from the authentication provider, that once authenticated successfully redirects back to the app)
- authenticated clients are granted access.

This requires a method to validate the header/cookie/session token the client submits in the reverse proxy. The advantage is of course that the applications exposed by the reverse proxy don't have to provide their own login/authentication methods.

For nginx a bit of lua code seems  to be a common way to create such a method.

For example the  [`access_by_lua`](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/#access_by_lua) method is commonly used to make such an integration with nginx and keycloak as the authentication provider. See the examples: [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/08/configuring-nginx-keycloak-oauth-oidc#) and [here](https://kevalnagda.github.io/configure-nginx-and-keycloak-to-enable-sso-for-proxied-applications)

Comment: This sounds great! In the meanwhile I found a better solution that is specific to my particular setup. (Backend A actually has authentication, it's just different from backend B.) But I'll come back to these `access_by_lua` examples if I need this in the future. Thanks!